# Get the address of a contract without using Remix-ide

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, error, debian

I'm studying Ethereum, I need to get the contract address for interact with web3, I can not use Remix-IDE for this since that I installed Kali as an operating system. How I get the contract address without Remix-IDE?

I appreciate any help. Thank u so much.

Comment: How are u deploying the contract ?

Comment: use truffle instead

Comment: @MrAbade
More details required. 
Is it contract you deployed? You want to deploy?
or is it some public contract?